# How to get the XSD out of a WSDL

Tags: .net, wsdl

I have a WSDL from the service provider, how can I extract the XSD out of it without manual copy and paste

Comment: There may be more than one XSD.

Comment: What do you mean "extract"? Are you looking to use it in an application that consumes the service?

Comment: yes, I need the schema so that I can create an xml and send over

Comment: Have you tried wsdl.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have perl installed, you'll probably also have the xpath program, in which case you can extract the schema with this:

```
xpath myfile.wsdl /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema > myfile.xsd
```

If you're doing this within .NET, you can still use XPath, but the details will depend on how exactly you've working with the WSDL.  Here's a page about using XPath in .NET which you might find useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164116.aspx